# Cannot Transfer File to USB (Too Large?)

Tags: windows, macos, usb, usb-drive

I bought a 64gb USB to install Windows on since my version of Windows corrupted. When I download the ISO and try to drag it to my USB it says that the file size is too large (even though it's less than 5gb). I was wondering if I was doing anything wrong here and if anyone could help me. Screenshots: https://prnt.sc/lq8dy2 https://prnt.sc/lq8dpx

Thank you!

Edit: Wrong section, was going to delete this post but someone already posted an answer.

Comment: General computer questions belong on Super User instead. This site is for help with code.

Answer (score 0):

Is your drive formatted to NTFS? If it is Formatted as Fat32 and the file size is larger than 4GB it won't work, because Fat32 only supports files up to 4GB.

Try formatting the USB Drive to NTFS and see if that works.